# objective C code for close a view

Tags: objective-c, subview, ibaction

What's the code in an IBAction for a button to close a subview?

Comment: Please try to explain your question a little bit better. Provide code samples if possible

Comment: What do you mean by closing a subview? Also, is your target Mac OS or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView *abc;
[self.view addSubview:self.view];
[abc removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using this code to remove the subview...

```
[subviewname removeFromSuperview];
```